# How to create a native installer in AIR. i.e Installer should be .exe, .deb, .dmg instead of .air

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I want to create a native installer for windows, mac and linux machines, Instead of .air file I want to create .exe , .dmg and .deb files respectively. 
So that i can enable the application to be installed natively.

Answer (score 3):

```
adt -package -target native target.exe source.air
```

adt comes from AIR SDK. For windows, you also need to have java 1.5 or higher on path for adt to work (not installed by default).

Edit: Instruction above are for windows. Also, on each platform it is possible to make native installer for this platform only - no cross-packaging exist for now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how do I install adt. I have air sdk. but i dont know how do I install adt. I found adt.jar in AIR 2.0 sdk. How do i get it to work for me?

Comment: You're going to have to use java to execute it, assuming java is in your path: java -jar adt -package -target native target.exe source.air

Comment: adt is located in the bin folder, if that is what you asked